# Customizing {drake} plan with {data.table}

Tags: r, ropensci, drake-r-package

My goal is to customize {drake} plan to reduce duplication of codes for both simple and complex cases, for example, setting `drake::trigger` for multiple targets based on specific conditions of the plans (ie programmatically identify the targets to be set by detecting names of targets that end with (data) **_raw** when querying web API or other more complex cases). For brevity, the aspects of *programmatically identifying targets are not shown here and the codes below simply use names of columns typed out manually. I prefer to use {data.table} to manipulate the plans, instead of {dplyr}.

Is there a way, for example, to set `drake::trigger` for multiple targets? Or is there a better way to get the job done?

I came out with a simple solution below, which is to manually manipulate the drake plan with the familiar *data.frame-style* methods. Simplified version of reprex

```r
library(drake)
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'purrr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     transpose
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
library(rlang)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:magrittr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int,
#>     flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along, modify, prepend,
#>     splice
#> The following object is masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     :=

trigger_func <- function(target_name) do_something(target_name)
# Helper func
reset_drake_attr <- function(data, command_names = command_names, ...) {
  # Reset original 'class' of drake plan
  setattr(data, 'class', c('drake_plan', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame'))
  # Remove non-drake attributes created by data.table
  map( setdiff( names(attributes(data)),
                c('names', 'row.names', 'class') ),
       ~ setattr(data, . , NULL))
  # TODO Comment this out temporarily for testing
  # setattr(data$command, 'names', command_names)
  invisible()
}

plan <- drake_plan(
  a = 1,
  b = target(2, trigger = trigger(condition = trigger_func('b'))),
  c = 3, d = 4,
  e = target(5, trigger = trigger(condition = trigger_func('e')))
)

# Manipulate plan with data.table ----------------

my_plan <- drake_plan(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5)

command_names <- names(my_plan$command)      # For testing later
setDT(my_plan)[, trigger := .(.(expr(NA)))]  # Pre-populate targets without trigger

map(c('b', 'e'),
    ~ my_plan [
      ][target == . , trigger := .(expr(
          trigger(condition = trigger_func(!!.))
      ))])
#> [[1]]
#>    target command trigger
#> 1:      a       1      NA
#> 2:      b       2  <call>
#> 3:      c       3      NA
#> 4:      d       4      NA
#> 5:      e       5  <call>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    target command trigger
#> 1:      a       1      NA
#> 2:      b       2  <call>
#> 3:      c       3      NA
#> 4:      d       4      NA
#> 5:      e       5  <call>

reset_drake_attr(my_plan)

# Test equality ----------------------------------

plan
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   target command trigger                               
#>   <chr>  <expr>  <expr>                                
#> 1 a      1       NA                                    
#> 2 b      2       trigger(condition = trigger_func("b"))
#> 3 c      3       NA                                    
#> 4 d      4       NA                                    
#> 5 e      5       trigger(condition = trigger_func("e"))
my_plan
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   target command trigger                               
#>   <chr>  <expr>  <expr>                                
#> 1 a      1       NA                                    
#> 2 b      2       trigger(condition = trigger_func("b"))
#> 3 c      3       NA                                    
#> 4 d      4       NA                                    
#> 5 e      5       trigger(condition = trigger_func("e"))

identical(plan, my_plan)
#> [1] FALSE
all.equal(plan$command, my_plan$command)
#> [1] "names for target but not for current"
# Reason: 
names(plan$command)
#> [1] "a" ""  "c" "d" ""
command_names           # Saved earlier
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
names(my_plan$command)  # data.table removes 'names' of 'my_plan$command'
#> NULL

# Can't test the exact equality of `identical(plan, my_plan)` because only targets without `target` have 'names' on 'command' column
drake_plan(
  # without `target`
  a = 1, b = 2,
  # with `target`
  c = target(3),
  d = target(4, trigger = trigger(condition = TRUE)),
  e = target(func(a), map(func = !!c('x', 'y')))
) %>%
  {names(.$command)}
#> [1] "a" "b" ""  ""  ""  ""

# Test without 'names' of 'command' column -------

identical( unname(plan$command), unname(my_plan$command) )
#> [1] TRUE
# Copy objects, remove 'names' of 'command' column and test
plan_test <- plan                ; my_plan_test <- my_plan
names(plan_test$command) <- NULL ; names(my_plan_test$command) <- NULL
identical(plan_test, my_plan_test)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Are *names* of **my_plan$command** necessary? Are they used by {drake} internally? I have three options and which options should I go for?

- ignore
- `names(my_plan$command) <- my_plan$target`
- Save `command_names <- names(my_plan$command)` and reset it back (like this)

```r
# Test with 'names' of 'command' column ----------

# --- NOT RUN ---
{
  # Put this in helper func, re-run `reset_drake_attr`
  setattr(my_plan$command, 'names', command_names)

  # (run manipulation steps...)

  reset_drake_attr(my_plan, command_names)  
  identical( names(my_plan$command), command_names )
  # TRUE 
}
```

Comment: I think there are easier way to identify subsets of targets you want. `names(plan$command)` is inconsistent and unreliable, and working with `plan$target` requires a lot of brittle text processing. But if you use [static branching](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/static.html) with `drake_plan(..., trace = TRUE)`, your plan will have special ID columns that carry information about groupings of targets. The static transforms (e.g. `map()`, `cross()`, `combine()`) respect the way triggers are supposed to map over the new targets.

Comment: @landau Thank you, yes I do use some information from ID columns, `map`, `combine`, etc when necessary. I think I didn't make my question clear enough. Basically I successfully manipulate drake plan and run the custom plans in my real project. But I want to make sure things are fine. When testing *equality* of the plans, I found `names(plan$command)` generated are inconsistent. Questions: What's purpose of auto-generated `names(plan$command)`? Are they important or being used in building targets? Would the targets fail because of erroneous `names(plan$command)`? Can I safely ignore them?

Comment: (cont...) If the names cannot be ignored, what should I do about it?
`names(my_plan$command) <- my_plan$target` or save `command_names <- names(my_plan$command)` and reset it back (see post above)

Comment: To be honest, those names in `plan$command` are totally accidental. In fact, I intend to remove them. To check for equality of plans, I recommend something like [this](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/1e66ad340ea0dc31179dad340657406ac62209bb/tests/testthat/helper-checkers.R#L10-L22), which deparses language objects into characters before comparing across plans. Language objects tend to be brittle. `deparse_lang_cols()` is an internal `drake` function [here](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/1e66ad340ea0dc31179dad340657406ac62209bb/R/drake_plan.R#L618-L631)...

Comment: ...and you can probably replace `safe_deparse()` with just `paste(deparse(...), collapse = "\n")`

Comment: Hmm... you know what? I actually *do* use the names of the commands, but only in the internal processing of the `drake_plan()` function. You can still ignore those names, I just remembered why they were there in the first place. Cleaning them up right now...